# How do I make text wrapping match current indentation level in vim?

Tags: python, vim, word-wrap

Does anyone know of a way to get vim to wrap long lines of text such that the position of the wrapped text is based on the indentation of the current line? I don't want to reformat my code, just for it to be displayed prettily.

For instance, if I set my settings so that the line:

```
print 'ProcessorError(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.file, self.index, self.message)
```

is displayed when wrapped as:

```
print 'ProcessorError(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.file, self.index,
    self.message)
```

then if I write a block of code like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ProcessorError(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.file, self.index, self.message)
```

it wraps to something like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ProcessorError(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.file, self.index,
    self.message)
```

I would prefer for it to be displayed as:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ProcessorError(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.file, self.index,
            self.message)
```

**Edit:** after reading Don Werve's response, it seems that I am indeed looking for the `breakindent` option, but the option is still on the "Awaiting updated patches" list (see [Vim TODO](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/todo.html)). So what I'd like to know is what is the *easiest way* to get vim working with `breakindent`? (I don't care what version of vim I have to use.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart Wrap in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `breakindent`

You may want to also refer to [this thread](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.editors/2005-07/msg00056.html).

Comment: For recent updates to the breakindent patch, see here: https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent

Answer (score 7):

I asked the [same question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/72714/vim-line-wrap-with-indent), eventually found this question, found the patch, and [updated the patch](https://retracile.net/blog/2009/11/20/12.00) to work with Vim 7.2.148 from Fedora 11.

You can use `yumdownloader --source vim` to get the source RPM.  Then add a `Patch3312:` line and a `%patch3012 -p1` line to the spec file, and build the rpm.

Comment: As Fedora releases updates to vim, I'm updating the patch.  See https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent for the latest.

Comment: Thanks for maintaining the patch.  I was able to successfully apply the 7.3 version on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried downloading the patch, but there is no link for it. Where can I find it? This is probably the one thing I want most right now.

Comment: A major software upgrade had left some broken links.  I've fixed them now.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this vimscript:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974

"This indentation script for python tries to match more closely what is suggested in PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0008.html).  In particular, it handles continuation lines implied by open (parentheses), [brackets] and {braces} correctly and it indents multiline if/for/while statements differently."

Comment: That's certainly a useful script, but it doesn't seem to do what I was actually asking. I want something to help with the visual position of long lines rather than with the position of automatic indentation.

Comment: That script will also add newlines and correctly indent long lines, so they become nicely formatted lines under 80 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

For controlling the indentation of Python code, see `:h ft-python-indent`.  This for example will make Vim indent two times the `shiftwidth` if you do a newline while there's an unclosed paren:

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren = '&sw * 2'
```

However `&sw * 2` is the default, so not sure why it's not working for you.  It works for me with manual newlines or with `textwidth`-induced newlines.

The above setting needs to be in `.vimrc` or needs to be set somehow before Vim enters Python mode.  Be sure to `:setf python` or that you're otherwise in Python mode.

Answer (score -2):

I think set textwidth=80 should do it.

Comment: This is not actually what the question was asking - the point was how Vim displays the code when it has to be wrapped to fit in the viewing window.