# Is there any way to indent wordwrapping acording to syntax in Vim?

Tags: html, vim, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smart Wrap in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim)

I want the wordwrapping to fit the 4 space tab width in my html file.

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1883/27258431.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1883/27258431.png)

I want the **Maecenas nisl quam** to follow the identation of the `li tag`

Is that possible (other than do it manually)?

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for this, but it's been lingering for *years* and last time I checked did not apply cleanly.  See last entry in http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/web/vim-patches
-- I really wish this would get in the mainline.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/72714/vim-line-wrap-with-indent

Essentially you can get closer, but with the built-in functionality you can't make it automatically match the arbitrary < li > level.