# Don't change indent level of wrapped lines

Tags: vim, indentation

If there are lines in a file that are too long to be displayed on the screen, we can use the
command

`:set wrap`

Now long lines are split into chunks visible on the screen. Usually the code is structured and indenting is used for readability, sometimes it's part of the syntax (Python).

If a line is wrapped into two (or more) lines, only the first line has right indenting
and the other lines begin at the beginning of a row.

If you use the command

`:set nowrap`

the line is visible only partially.

Could this behavior be changed via `vimscript` so that **all** of the **wrapped lines** have the **same indent level**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smart Wrap in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204149/smart-wrap-in-vim) — search before asking

Comment: You shouldn't have lines long enough to wrap in the first place.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, difficult to impose on everyone and everything. Have you ever seen deeply nested XML?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus people This may be a little hard to grasp, but people do sometimes write text that's not code... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, unfortunately there is no such feature in Vim 7.3 yet, if you fancy a patch you can find a link to it below.

However there are 2 things that might help you improve readability for long code lines:

```
:set nu
```

Line numbering is used by most people editing and debugging code. A long line will have no numbers on it's wrappings clearly disambiguating code's indentation from wrapped line.

```
:set sbr=>\
```

A fixed marker to display on all wrappings (i.e. `">\ "`). It only supports a static marker string, not based on the line's indentation.

You can combine these options and if you want the marker to be displayed in-line with line numbers you can:

```
:set cpoptions+=n
```

*Patch:* If you really need this feature you can try this patch:

> https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent

the option is supposed to be:

```
:set breakindent
```

It would be nice indeed if someone would pick it up in the source base.