# Vim soft wrap with autoindent

Tags: vim, auto-indent

In Vim, is there a way to soft wrap the text, autoindent, but also to give the appearance that soft wrapped lines are autoindented?

E.g. rather than:

```
1 hello
2     one two three four five six seven eight nine 
  ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen 
  seventeen 
3 blah blah
```

I want it to look the like the following:

```
1 hello
2     one two three four five six seven eight nine 
      ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen 
      sixteen seventeen 
3 blah blah
```

But for the text file in actual fact to be as follows:

```
1 hello
2     one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen 
3 blah blah
```

So there are no actual tabs (or blocks of 4 spaces) between `nine` and `ten` or between `fifteen` and `sixteen` - this is just part of how the text is displayed in Vim, not the contents of the file.

Some other text editors (e.g. Geany) seem to do this automatically, but I can't find out how to do this in Vim.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: ["Smart Wrap in Vim"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1204149).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not the first to ask about that feature. Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to achieve that effect with Vim.

But you can re-build Vim with [the `breakindent` patch](https://retracile.net/wiki/VimBreakIndent) and get what you want.

Comment: The patch is officially part of Vim now.